# Imported pallet and got "use codec::alloc::vec;"

Tags: frame

I work on a pallet with interior dispatch mutability where I need to make calls `cancel_as_multi` and `as_multi` and after importing `contracts` pallet, compiler forces me to change `contracts` pallet. But I do not want to change `contracts` pallet, and I completely do not understand **why** compiler forces me to implement those changes. Here is what I got from a compiler:

```
   Compiling pallet-contracts v4.0.0-dev (/home/tomek/workspaces/polkadot-sdk/substrate/frame/contracts) error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope    --> substrate/frame/contracts/src/wasm/mod.rs:272:7
    | 272 |                         vec![code_hash],
    |                         ^^^
    | help: consider importing one of these items
    | 30  + use codec::alloc::vec;
    | 30  + use crate::vec;
    | 30  + use scale_info::prelude::vec;
    | 30  + use sp_api::vec;
    |
      and 1 other candidate
```

This kind of errors I got many, many more but all connected to `use codec::alloc::vec;`. I have no idea why, can anyone explain **the way**? I do not understand the mechanism that works behind. I ask the question because I was assuming, that just the fact of importing a pallet should not induce any changes in the imported pallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, if you forget to include `xxx/std` in the features, you will encounter this error.

Comment: Right, forgot to import xxx/std ;/ Thanks!!